# How to center the components inside navbar

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4, navbar

i have a navbar like this:
https://i.ibb.co/28MgmFt/navbar2.jpg

i'm trying to align the components inside a navbar to look like this:

with this code HTML:

```
 <!-- Navbar -->
 <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark scrolling-navbar">
  <div style="text-align: center; list-style: inside;" class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="assets/img/logo.png" width="135px" alt="">
    </a>

    <!-- Collapse -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <!-- Left -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; font-size:18px; color: #0f3832; font-weight: bold;" class="nav-link border-bottom border-dark rounded-left" href="#howtocon" target="_blank">طريقة المشاركة</a>
        </li>
        &nbsp;
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; font-size:18px; color: #0f3832; font-weight: bold;" class="nav-link border-bottom border-dark" href="#branchess" target="_blank">فروع الجائزة</a>
        </li>
        &nbsp;
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; font-size:18px; color: #0f3832; font-weight: bold;" class="nav-link border-bottom border-dark" href="#about" target="_blank">عن الجائزة</a>
        </li>
        &nbsp;
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; font-size:18px; color: #0f3832; font-weight: bold;" class="nav-link border-bottom border-dark rounded-right" href="#headerstart">الرئيسية
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Right -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a style="background-color: #0f3832;font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; font-size:18px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;" href="/login" class="nav-link border border-dark rounded"
            >
            <i class="mr-2"></i> تسجيل الدخول
          </a>
        </li>
&nbsp;            <li class="nav-item">
          <a style="background-color: #0f3832;font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; font-size:18px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;" href="/register" class="nav-link border border-dark rounded"
            >
            <i class="mr-2"></i>تسجيل جديد
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>


  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Navbar -->
```

i want to make it like this:
https://i.ibb.co/1ZbKrtC/navbar1.jpg

i tried many methods to do it but i couldn't

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change margin of ul   from ml-auto to mx-auto
code here:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this CSS code:

```
.navbar-nav.mr-auto {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```